# Error while installing Ephesoft

Tags: ephesoft

im new working with linux OSs, i would like to install Ephesotf  but the point is that im having trouble while i am trying to install Ephesoft version 4.0.2.0 in ubuntu 16.10, the error is this below:

Updating paths in properties file. Please wait...
Installing/Updating "libpng12-dev" for Ephesoft.
E: Package 'libpng12-dev' has no installation candidate
Error occurred while installing "libpng12-dev"
Exiting from script...

I have been trying to install it separeted but im failing, so like this i can´t move on, please help me.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that Ubuntu 16.x is not supported by Ephesoft:
http://wiki.ephesoft.com/linux-4-x-release

You can update the installer script but I won't recommend it. I'll just switch to a supported Linux OS.

Ben

Comment: hi Ben, yeh i did it, i moved to ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and make it, but now i cant move forward because of libreoffice, having error:Installing Libreoffice.
Please Wait....
Error in installing Libreoffice
Exiting from script, do you have any clue?

Comment: Hi. I had the same error. I had to install LibreOffice manually first: `aptitude install -y libreoffice`

Comment: Hi Ben, im uninstalling and installing over and over again, but still the same prob, i dont know what to do, i cant move forward with ephesoft installation like this... do u have any other clue?

Comment: Did you installed libreoffice first? If you are stuck, check the log file generated by the ephesoft installer. It should be in `/var/log/install-ephesoft.log`. It will give you exactly why it fails on your server.

Comment: Hi Ben, may you tell me the version of ephesoft u r using, plz?

Comment: Hi BEN, look i First I removed the libreoffice that came with my OS, then I installed a new one, then I started installing ephesoft again, I had a problem when ephesoft installer tried to install libreoffice, now im removing everything that has to do with libreoffice in the install-helper, to see if something happens

Comment: Good. And look at the log file to have technical details on why it fails.

Comment: Hi Ben, "im really sorry if i´m boldering u, bt im freaking out" i´ve removed everything about libreofice from install-helper & is nt giving me error anymore although i think is nt the right way to do it, now the same prob i had with libreoffice im having with ghostscript: Building the library & shared library 4 Ghostscript.
Error occurred while building the libraries 4 Ghostscript.
Exiting from script. im afraid to be removing all th dependencies then ephesoft will nt work properly & the .log file gives me th same prob above mentioned & i already tried manually install ghsscript bt still.

Comment: if u would like, i can send u the .log file (cause still there many lines that i did not understand), i dont know what to do, i tried last ime to replace the libreoffice version within ephesoft.tar.gz and put a new one but did not work, thn i removed from install-helper, now is ghostscript, as i said im afraid to be removing everything that gets stack then ephesoft just do not work, myb instead to be removing i should code something in the install-helper file, but i dont know how and what to do...

Comment: Hi. Just look at the latest error in the log file and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while I was trying to install Ephesoft community software on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tried all the things that you have metioned MGM. Finally I found out that ephesoft currently does not support 16.04 LTS and only works for ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 14.10 as they have mentioned on their website. They may release an update for 16.04 LTS in 2018. I am sorry I don't have the url where I read that as of now. 
I installed ubuntu 14.04 currently and it installs perfectly there. There is very less help on using this software's community version though.